# Getting library from java class name and namespace

Tags: java, jboss

Well I think this is a kind of weird question but here it goes (I'm not a Jboss expert so please correct me if I am wrong in something).

I have several imports in a java class:

```
import org.xyz.public.OneClass;
import org.abc.public.AnotherClass;
```

And I have deployed this class in an EAR component in a Jboss 4.2 server, so this EAR will pick up a library from the runtime enviroment (Jobss libs). So, for example, for OneClass it will pick up the library xyz-commons-3.4.jar.

What I need is a method to know what library is going to be chosen, before it gets chosen.

Well although a bit weird, I will tell you why do we need that.

There are several Jboss servers with a lot of EAR components, and we have to get all dependencies programmatically to show some kind of a report. So we have to make a shell script or a stand alone app to get these dependencies. But we don't have the sources, only the packaged EARs. And libraries are picked up by Jboss from Jboss eviroment (Jboss libs), so we don't have library references in EARs.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to re-invent the wheel. You can just use [Tattletale](http://tattletale.jboss.org/) for your purpose from the JBoss community. It will generate the dependency report that you are looking for and has many other useful features.

Comment: Thank you CoolBeans. The problem with Tattletale as I see, is a bit abandoned software.
Latest release is a beta from 2012:
1.2.0.Beta2 2012-02-17
I'm going to try it anyway.
Thanks a lot!.

Comment: It did just what I needed. :)